# After the second press, I need to return the button to its original state and so that it can work again

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        editText.setEnabled(true);
        name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button1.setText("Confirm");
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                editText.setEnabled(false);
                name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button1.setText("Edit");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I wanted to change the information of the button from "edit" to "confirm", and return it to its original state on the second press, but on the third press it does not work

Comment: You need to create a logic there, something like, if else.

Comment: @Ticherhaz how?

Comment: Create a boolen at the MainActivity, boolean isClicked = false. then at the button check if click else, then change the value of isClicked = true

Comment: @Ticherhaz I tried to do as you said, but now only the first action works, 
Can you describe the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have class `MainActivity.java`. Inside the class, create a variable named `isClicked`.

```
private boolean isClicked = false;
```

At your button `onClicked`, implement the logic condition. Something like this.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (isClicked) {
         isClicked = false;
         editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         editText.setEnabled(true);
         name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         button1.setText("Confirm");
    } else {
         isClicked = true;
         editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         editText.setEnabled(false);
         name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         button1.setText("Edit");
    }
}
});
```